# How to call product new.phtml in admin cms home page magento 2.2.6

Tags: template, cms-block, magento2.2.6

How to call new.phtml file in the home page admin Magento 2.2.6 version?

Please check my screenshot link here http://prntscr.com/lapiu7.

And also check my theme default.xml code.

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list"   >
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/new.phtml</argument>
    </action>
```

Then after that, I put the code in my cms home page admin.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="new_file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/new.phtml"}}
```

http://prntscr.com/lapk4g

But it's not working.

Please let me know how to implement custom product slider in Magento 2.2.6

http://prntscr.com/lazzuu

Comment: your code is working..i have checked it. try to put `die("hello")` in your new.phtml file

Comment: ok let me check again

Comment: check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170294/magento-2-how-to-show-custom-product-slider-on-home-page) for custom product slider

Comment: yes" hello" print

Comment: please check i make same slider like this "http://prntscr.com/lb04wn" please check screenshort.

Comment: instead of duplicate question close previous one i.e https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248030/how-to-call-product-new-phtml-in-admin-cms-page-magento-2-2-6

Comment: i closed previous question

Comment: do you want to show new product on home page with default phtml file ?

Comment: yes "http://prntscr.com/lb0gnb" please check this screenshot .

Comment: Please see my answer, if have any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show `New Product` with default phtml, You can call below code to home page.

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="new_products" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}
```

Above code will show new products.
If you want to change design, you need to copy above phtml to your custom theme with following path.

> app/design/frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml

Please make sure there are new product available in admin with applicable  date

IF found suitable accept and Up-vote as a token of appreciation

Comment: its working but how we can overwrite this file. after that "http://prntscr.com/lb0uis" please check all catelog files paste in our custom theme.

Comment: You can copy file at : app/design/frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml

Comment: great, welcome :)